# "They have agreed [to get]/[getting] a divorce."

Tags: difference, verbs

> They have agreed to get a divorce.

> They have agreed getting a divorce.

Is there any difference here, or not?

Comment: The phrase _getting divorce_ is ungrammatical. The best way I could make it work using those two words would be something like: _They have agreed, getting **a** divorce is their best option right now._ You need to either use an article, or use the phrase "getting divorced".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> They have agreed to get a divorce - is correct

This is the exact example mentioned in [Oxford Learner's Dictionaries](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/divorce_1).

However, I don't completely agree with user3169...

> They are **getting married.** - is fine.

Comment: As a footnote, ***They are getting divorced*** is also fine.

Answer (score 2):

> They have agreed getting divorce.

is incorrect. *getting* is a present participle verb form of *get*, that requires an auxiliary (helping) verb, which is not in this sentence.

However you could say:

> They **are getting** a divorce.

Comment: *They are **getting married** - getting is not followed by an auxiliary verb here.